# Make a list of a class's methods and dynamically call the methods on the class

Tags: python, class, methods

Is it possible to get a list of class's methods and then invoke the methods on an instance of the class?  I have come across code that makes a list of a class's methods, but I haven't found an example that also invokes the methods on an instance of the class.

Given the class:

```
class Test:

def methodOne(self):
    print 'Executed method one'


def methodTwo(self):
    print 'Executed method two'
```

And you make a list of the class's methods:

```
import inspect

a = Test()

methodList = [n for n, v in inspect.getmembers(a, inspect.ismethod)]
```

I would like to invoke every method in the `methodList` on an instance of the class, like:

```
for method in methodList:
     a.method()
```

The result would be equivalent to:

```
a.methodOne()
a.methodTwo()
```

Comment: congrats: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/1000000th-user/

Answer (score 9):

Use `getattr(a,methodname)` to access the actual method, given the string name, `methodname`:

```
import inspect
import types

class Test(object):
   def methodOne(self):
      print('one')
   def methodTwo(self):
      print('two')

a = Test()    
methodList = [n for n, v in inspect.getmembers(a, inspect.ismethod)
              if isinstance(v,types.MethodType)]

for methodname in methodList:
   func=getattr(a,methodname)
   func()
```

yields

```
one
two
```

---

As [Jochen Ritzel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074122/make-a-list-of-a-classs-methods-and-dynamically-call-the-methods-on-the-class/6074921#6074921) points out, if you are more interested in the actual methods (callable objects) than the method names (strings), then you should change the definition of `methodList` to

```
methodList = [v for n, v in inspect.getmembers(a, inspect.ismethod)
              if isinstance(v,types.MethodType)]
```

so you could call the methods directly without needing `getattr`:

```
for method in methodList:
    method()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call your dynamically obtained methods like this:

```
for method in methodList:
    getattr(a, method)()
```

But the problem you will have is that this code will only work for methods that don't take any parameters.

Comment: method is a string and not callable. According to my interpreter.

Comment: In his example, `methodList` is a list of the names of the methods, as strings.

Comment: @Will Thanks, I assumed it was the actual method.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you keep the name of the method and not the method itself? `inspect.getmembers` returns bound method's which can be called directly:

```
for name, method in inspect.getmembers(a, inspect.ismethod):
    print "Method", name, "returns", method()
```

Comment: when I run your code the methods are being dynamically invoked.  I understand that part.  However, after each iteration "None" is also returned.  Where is the 'None' coming from?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @9monkeys: Methods that return nothing (like your example methods) return `None` instead, maybe you mean that?

Comment: Yes. I think I understand now.  "print" is not returning anything, it is simply printing to screen. Therefore, "None" is returned. Is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As David Heffernan pointed out, this will only work for methods that don't take any parameters.

```
for method in methodList:
    getattr(a, method)()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for method in methodList: eval ("a.%s()" % method)
```

For method without parameters except self.

Comment: No need for `eval` in this case.

Comment: @Will. As in the example given, we have the methods only as textual representation (string), how do you call a string without eval?

Comment: see the other answers: `getattr(obj, name)` will get you a reference to the method, which you can call just by adding parentheses: `getattr(obj, name)()`

Comment: @Will Thank you. I was just orienting myself on the code snippet OP had posted.